# Change Navigation Bar Title when different tab is selected

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uinavigationbar

I am still fairly new to xcode.

I am trying to programatically change the navigation title when different tabs are selected in my `UITabBarController`.

I have a `UItabBarController` that creates the tab bar, then I have separate `UIViewControllers` which have different content for each of the tabs - this part works fine, however I cannot get the navigation title to change when different tabs are selected.

Here is the code for the main tab controller.

```
// SUPER VIEW DID LOAD

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    // NAVIGATION ITEM
    navigationItem.title = "Job Information"
    navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
    
    //setup our custom view controllers
    
    let jobInfo = page_jobInfo()
    let shots = page_shotList()
    let attachments = page_attachments()
    let notes = page_notes()
    
    jobInfo.tabBarItem.title = "Information"
    jobInfo.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: "jobInfo")
    
    shots.tabBarItem.title = "Shots"
    shots.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: "shots")
    
    attachments.tabBarItem.title = "Attachments"
    attachments.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: "attachments")
    
    notes.tabBarItem.title = "Notes"
    notes.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: "notes")
    
    viewControllers = [jobInfo, shots, attachments, notes]
}
```

Here is the code for the second tab button - The other 2 tabs are the same as this so didn't want to spam this feed with huge amounts of code.

```
// SUPER VIEW DID LOAD

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    // NAVIGATION ITEM
    navigationItem.title = "Shot List"
    navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
    
}
```

Comment: do you have tabBarController pushed to navigationController?

Comment: I have the tabBarController as my top level then 4 different TableViewControllers which represent each of the tab buttons. I am setting the titles of the NavigationBar in the view did load.

Comment: but where is the navigation bar set? by default tabController nor tableViewController dont have navigationBar

Comment: I cannot see anywhere I have set this apart from this line in my app delegate. Where I have window?.rootViewController =
            UINavigationController(rootViewController: page_jobList())

Comment: I want to see the code/storyboard where you set that navigationBar.. without knowing that we can just guess

Comment: Thank you for your help but @DanKarbay 's answer worked.

Comment: I was getting there, but I wanted to be sure

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since your view controllers are embedded in `UITabBarController`, you should change its (tab bar controller's) navigationItem. Moreover, you should do that in `viewWillAppear` method instead of `viewDidLoad`, like so:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
  super.viewWillAppear(animated)
  self.tabBarController?.navigationItem.title = "Bookmarks"
}
```